# Simplifying a pivot table query

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table

I have a pivot table, but my issue is, once a year, it needs manually modifying and it shouldnt have to be that way.

What i currently have is:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT Injuries.PlayerID, InjuryID, YEAR(DateInjured) AS YearInjured, (YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - YEAR(DateOfBirth)) AS Age FROM Injuries INNER JOIN Players ON (Players.PlayerID = Injuries.PlayerID)) AS T
PIVOT (
    COUNT(InjuryID)
    FOR YearInjured IN ([2008],[2009],[2010],[2011],[2012],[2013],[2014],[2015])
) AS PT
```

I have tried

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT Injuries.PlayerID, InjuryID, YEAR(DateInjured) AS YearInjured, (YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - YEAR(DateOfBirth)) AS Age FROM Injuries INNER JOIN Players ON (Players.PlayerID = Injuries.PlayerID)) AS T
PIVOT (
    COUNT(InjuryID)
    FOR YearInjured IN (SELECT DISTICT YEAR(DateInjured) FROM Injuries)
) AS PT
```

But SQL server does not like me doing that. I have also attempted to `DECLARE` a table and select the years into that and use that within the PIVOT, but that does not seem to work too.

Is there a way, without being forced to use `sp_exec` and a generated query, to do what i am trying to do?

Comment: You want a dynamic pivot.  It requires either manual intervention or dynamic SQL.

Comment: Do you need the columns to be named by the absolute year, or would the relative year be acceptable? Have you tried using SSRS (or EXCEL) as your reporting medium, as it can dynamically name the columns? Have you tried doing a UNION of one query with the column headings and a second with the data?

Comment: What is the error when trying to do the second query?

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near 'DateInjured'.

Comment: @bizzehdee are you sure the format that year(dateInjured) returns is equal to the format of yearInjured ?

Comment: might be worth noting that if you use `(YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - YEAR(DateOfBirth)) AS Age` to get someone's age, you might offend them.

Comment: its a rough estimate of somebodies age and irrelevant to the question

Comment: apparently the search box is irrelevant also